# When using @Published and a protocol in EnvironmentObject I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using @EnvironmentObject in a view where the EnvironmentObject is conforming to a protocol where a variable that needs to be Published is defined.
When MyView is in a separate file, I get a crash. When all the code is in the SceneDelegate file, there is no crash. Can someone confirm the same behavior? This behavior is very unexpected.

Any idea how to fix this?

This code reproduces the problem:

```
//MyView.swift
import SwiftUI    
import Combine

struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MyViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if self.viewModel.someText == nil { //<--Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
                Text("nil")
            } else {
                Text("not nil")
            }
        }
    }
}


//SceneDelegate.swift
import SwiftUI    
import Combine 

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject & HasText {
    @Published var someText: String?
    var someTextPublished: Published<String?> { _someText }
    var someTextPublisher: Published<String?>.Publisher { $someText }

    init() {}   
}

protocol HasText: AnyObject {
    var someText: String? { get set }
    var someTextPublished: Published<String?> { get }
    var someTextPublisher: Published<String?>.Publisher { get }
}

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    let viewModel = MyViewModel()
    let contentView = MyView().environmentObject(viewModel)

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Comment: Provided code works fine. Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2. And I don't see any reason to crash. Is this the only exact code you use?

Comment: Yes I created a new project with the code I provide in the question. I use XCode 11.3 and iOS 13.2 on iPhone 8 simulator. When removing "HasText" from MyViewModel, there is no crash.

Comment: Tested ... not crashing ... XCode 11.3

Comment: I was able to isolate the problem further. When MyView is in a separate file, then there is a crash. When all the code is in the SceneDelegate file, there is no crash. Very unexpected.

Comment: @DevB2F, have you resolved this issue? Currently facing it now too.